# mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

I started using `mysqli_*` functions instead of the old `mysql_*` functions in PHP, and I'm having a bit of a problem with this code:

```
public function addUser($table, $code = false, $rows = false) {
   if (!$code) {
      header("Location: " . $this->authenticate());
   } else {
      $this->getToken($code);
   }
   $user = $this->getEndpoint('users/current', false, true);
   $user = $user->response->user;
   if (!$rows)
        $rows = array(
            "remote_id" => $user->id,
            "firstName" => $user->first_name,
            "lastName" => $user->last_name,
            "photo" => $user->photo->medium,
            "gender" => $user->gender == 'male' ? 1 : 2,
            "email" => $user->contact->email,
        );
   $rows['access_token'] = $this->accessToken;
   $stmt = $this->mysql->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE access_token = '{$this->accessToken}'"); //line 136
   $stmt->execute(); //line 137
}
```

The code returns these 2 errors:

> Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch MySQL in C:\Users\Grega\Server\application\inc\classes\APIConnect.php on line 136
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\Users\Grega\Server\application\inc\classes\APIConnect.php on line 137

What is the reason for 'Couldn't fetch MySQL'? The database connection is correct, it works in other classes, and the query returns a valid result, if I echo it and execute it in phpMyAdmin. Also, my variable is named `mysql` NOT `mysqli`!

Comment: That is **not** the way to use prepared statements. You aren't preparing anything.

Comment: A useful link: http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Comment: WHY did you accept the answer below if it doesn't solve your problem? And not even close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read more about the difference between MYSQL to MYSQLi.

While your code is:

```
$stmt = $this->mysql->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE access_token = '{$this->accessToken}'");
```

You should do it like this:

```
$stmt = $this->mysql->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE access_token = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s" , $this->accessToken ); //Used 's' as I guess that the accessToken is a string
```

The `binding` part is the critical part of the `prepare` thing. (Your queries are safe)

After that you can use `$stmt->execute();` and `get_result()`.

Comment: Please add about named bindings too, like `:access_token` instead of `?` to cover all areas. :)

Comment: As far as I know , mysqli doesn't support in named binding , unlike PDO.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the ::prepare method, but this doesn't fix anything. I still get the same error, also using any other method will return the same error.

Comment: @OfirBaruch, Oh sorry. My mistake. You're right... [PDO Vs Mysql](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/)

Comment: @GregaMenih , can you edit your question and paste the new code?

Comment: @OfirBaruch can *you* edit your answer that has **absolutely nothing to do with the question asked**, specifically the error message "Couldn't fetch mysqli"?

Answer (score 0):

For the first error: you probably closed the connection somewhere before this code, and this is why ($stmt -> close() )

For the second error: when you use (prepare()), you first introduce a SQL template to the database, which then has to pass the parameters to the "bind_param()" method to send it to the database with another protocol (to prevent SQL injection) and reduce the request and attach the parameters to SQL with execute() method